# Вертикальное выравнивание текста по нижней границе при фиксированной высоте <li> в css

Tags: css

Как сделать так, чтобы в списке элементов `<li>` с фиксированной высотой `max-height:10px`выравнивание при любом увеличении шрифта (`font-size`) происходило по нижней границе (размеры `<li>` при этом не меняются)?

В Chrome это автоматически происходит по верхней границе так (зелёный - элемент `<li>`, красный - текст, а слева просто отступ):
[image]

А нужно так:
[image]

Сделайте плиз список (с фиксированной высотой `<li>` 10px) на 3 элемента с разным размером шрифта (10, 20, 30) с выравниванием по нижней границе. То, что текст будет накладываться друг на друга, то так и должно быть. Все `<li>` должны быть абсолютно одинакового размера, а шрифт разного. Нижняя граница шрифта должна быть статической и всегда совпадать с нижней границей `<li>` (хотя бы на глаз).

То есть сутью вопроса является привязывание нижней границы шрифта к нижней границе элемента. Нужно, чтобы она всегда была одинаковой, если размер шрифта произвольно менять. Также должно работать при изменении шрифта через `font-family`.

Comment: Вы бы полностью css/html показали, а то так гадание на кофейной гуще получается

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Задачка была интересной. На первый взгляд все очень просто, но, пришлось поковыряться немного)

```css
ul,
li {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  align-items: flex-end; /* Отправляем вложенные элементы в нижнюю часть пунктов маркированного списка */
  list-style: none;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

span {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;  /* Задаем высоту. Значение указываем такое, чтоб блок был больше размера текста */
}

span:before { /* Небольшой хак по перемещению текста внутри родителя */
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;  /* Благодаря данному стилю текст выравнивается по базовой линии родителя и любой шрифт будет отображаться ровно по низу списка */
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="font-size: 10px;"><span>10px</span></li>
  <li style="font-size: 20px;"><span>20px</span></li>
  <li style="font-size: 30px;"><span>30px</span></li>
  <li style="font-size: 40px;"><span>40px</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Очень крутой результат, особенно то, что работает для разных шрифтов. А какое свойство поменять, чтобы `<li>` отображались не в линию, а один под другим?

Comment: @oleedd лучше покажите, что верстаете, так будет проще. А чтоб список был не в линию, удалите из примера `ul,`. Именно стиль `display: flex;` выстраивает пункты списка в строку.

Comment: Пока ничего не верстаю. Просто проверяю, как оно работает. Если удалить `<ul>`, то сильно большое расстояние между `<li>` (а нужно 0) + они все очень длинные. Что поменять, чтобы был такой же результат, только по вертикали: https://i.imgur.com/vhnqev1.png ? А шрифты пусть накладываются. (Ответ менять не надо, если много изменений, то можно вторым вариантом ниже.)

Comment: @oleedd вот [такой](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zbWQwd) результат вам нужен?

Comment: Да, круто. А ссылка не перестанет работать?

Comment: @oleedd не перестанет

Comment: Интересно, а без внутренних `<span>` элементов такое организовать теоретически возможно?

Comment: @oleedd думаю, что нет

Answer (score 1):

Как то так, но очень ситуационно:

```css
ul{
    font-size:0;
}
ul li{
    width:100px;
    height: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid red;
    line-height: 0;
    position:relative;
}
ul li span{
    line-height:75%;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <span style="font-size: 10px;">text</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span style="font-size: 20px;">text</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span style="font-size: 30px;">text</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span style="font-size: 50px;">text</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span style="font-size: 100px;">text</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Попробуйте запустить у себя, здесь кривовато показывает. У меня вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению, не подходит, так как если выставить размер шрифта больше, то нижняя граница съезжает вниз, а если меньше - то съезжает вверх. А нужно, чтобы нижняя граница всегда была одинаковой при любом размере шрифта.

Comment: Может есть формула с `line-height`?

Comment: @oleedd переписал с абсолютным позиционированием

Comment: У меня Chrome совсем не так показывает, а чуть выше над линией.
https://i.imgur.com/pncVc0c.png

Comment: @oleedd играйтесь с `line-height` значит, которое сейчас 75%

Comment: Совсем не хочется использовать абсолютное позиционирование, но тем не менее это пока единственный рабочий вариант.

Comment: @oleedd может кто-то предложит более лучшее решение, пока это все что я смог придумать на скорую руку

Comment: Да, пасибо. Лайк поставил)

Comment: В данном варианте решения через абсолютное позиционирование при небольшом размере текст находится на глаз примерно на линии. Но если выставить большие значения, то шрифт заметно опускается под линию. А это значит, что нижняя граница шрифта всё-таки не статическая. Иначе оно бы совпадало по линии с маленьким размером https://i.imgur.com/Y6urZC4.png

Comment: @oleedd ну, если у вас в дизайне есть шрифт размером Over9000px, то да, не подойдет, а еще можно облить кислотой дизайнера или заказчика за такой дизайн/ТЗ))

Comment: Да нет, это я выставлял только 800px (меньше тысячи).

Answer (score 1):

Вот специально для тебя простое решение, держи:

```css
li {
    height: 10px;
    max-height: 10px;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    align-items: flex-end;
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 50vh;
}
li span {
    font-size: 54px;
    line-height: 0.68;
    line-height: 0.5;
    font-family: Monotype Corsiva !important;
}
```

```html
<li><span>Любой текст</span></li>
```

Экспериментируй с line-height

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91101/discussion-on-answer-by-vladimir-rodichev-----).

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Как сделать, чтобы оповещения о новых сообщениях чата отображались на этом поддомене (так же, как и новые комментарии отображаются во входящих сообщениях)?

Comment: @oleedd, для этого в чате надо или ответить на сообщение человека (т.е. нажать на его сообщение, чтобы ID оного подставилось в поле ввода) или упомянуть его там через `@`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Не помешало бы добавить такую опцию "оповещения о новых сообщения чата". Да и вообще почему сообщение в чате можно удалить только первые 3 минуты (тут же нормально всё удаляется в любое время)?

Comment: @oleedd, возможно такое и сделают, если на основной мете написать разработчикам) Про ограничения на удаление ничего не знаю - я всё и всегда могу удалять)))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Тут можно, а в чате после 3 минут нельзя удалить. Вот проверьте. Или у меня баллов не достаточно?

Comment: @oleedd, чтобы мне проверить - мне надо второй акк заводить без модераторских прав) А это не совсем в правилах сайта)

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов для твоего решения:

```css
li {
    height: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<li>Любой текст</li>
```

Остальные сам.

Comment: текст на middle а не в низу ...

Comment: Это интересно. Но чем больше шрифт, тем выше он поднимается над нижней линией. Если поставить `font-size` 40, то он вообще будет на верхней линии. В данном варианте оно не подходит как решение, так как позиция нижней границы шрифта должна быть статической. Можно что-то с этим сделать?

Comment: @oleedd  если подумать то вот так можно решить эту проблему :https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/rRdjbE

Comment: Та нет. Сутью вопроса является привязывание нижней границы шрифта к нижней границе элемента. А чем больше шрифт, тем выше оно поднимается. Похожее решение сам нашёл. Но оно тоже не статическое, а, наоборот, вниз опускается при увеличении шрифта (((

Comment: @oleedd  там надо манипулировать и line-height и font-size одновременно

Comment: Да, тот второй способ, что я нашёл, через `line-height: 10px`. Он работает лучше, чем способ выше, так сдвиг не такой большой при увеличении шрифта. Но тем не менее этот сдвиг есть, а нужно, чтобы его не было. Если мыслить логически, то браузер изначально автоматически сдвигает шрифт по верхней границе, а значит, должно быть css свойство (или что-то типа того), на основе которого он это делает.

Comment: @oleedd  а теперя размер шрифта запишите в переменную css и эту переменную вставьте в line-height + font-size и увидите хороший вариант

Comment: Если `line-height:10px` (так как высота `<li>` - 10px), а `font-size:50px`, то что куда вставлять?

Comment: @oleedd  я ошибся ...но скажите для чего это надо ? странный головняк какой то \

Comment: Заметил, что если сам шрифт мелкий в таблице/списке, то он даже до верха элемента не достаёт и очень плохо видно текст. А если увеличить его, то и все строки расширяются. Вот и появился вопрос, как так увеличить шрифт, чтобы размер строк/элементов не менялся. Ну и конечно же, чтобы текст был ровно по линии и не съезжал вниз/вверх. В общем стало очень интересно. Но то, что успел найти в гугле, не работало. Надоело искать и решил спросить.

Answer (score 0):

```css
li {
    height: 10px;
    line-height: 1;
    max-height: 10px;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
li span {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: calc(-30px / 2);
    line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<li><span>Любой текст</span></li>
```

Немного объясню:

```
font-size: 30px;
```

Тут вместо 30px - пишите нужный размер вам.

```
margin-top: calc(-30px / 2);
```

Тот размер, который указали в font-size, чтобы не высчитывать самому, меняете в калке цифру "-30px" на ту, что в font-size.

Вот такое решение и ему тоже есть место.

Comment: Оно чуть съезжает. 30/-30 - чуть над линией. 70/-70 - под линией. Если взять 200/-200 - то вообще весь текст под линией.

Comment: @oleedd - это зависит от шрифта. Варианты можно подогнать. Alexey Giryayev прислал тебе похожий вариант, но дополненный, как он назвал с «хаком». Варианты есть, чтобы создать решения.

Comment: @oleedd Смотри простое решение новое. Я тебя не сразу понял чего ты хочешь. К линии приклеить впритык.